# Extracting the functional form of the likelihood function that gets formed by the msm function in R

Tags: r

Is there a way of extracting the functional form of the likelihood function that gets formed by the msm function in R?

How can I extract the likelihood function that gets formed in the example below? I want to try and implement my own version of the quasi-Newton maximisation algorithm to improve my understanding.

```
library(msm)

# look at transition counts
statetable.msm(state, PTNUM, data = cav)

# define transition intensity matrix
# 1's mean a transition can occur
# 0's mean a transition should not occur
# any number can be placed on the diagonal as R overwrites the diagonals 
# prior to maximising
q <- rbind(
  c(0, 1, 0, 1),
  c(1, 0, 1, 1),
  c(0, 1, 0, 1),
  c(0, 0, 0, 0)
  )


# fit msm to the data
# the fnscale rescales the likelihood to prevent overflow
msm.fit <- msm(state ~ years, PTNUM, data = cav, qmatrix = q, control=list(fnscale=4000))
```

Comment: Try debug(msn). This was you can step through the function.

Comment: I have tried using trace(msm, edit = TRUE). The code is very dense.

Comment: The package is "msm", by Chris Jackson. See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/vignettes/msm-manual.pdf.

Comment: You should contact the author of the package. You can also provide a link to this question.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm also interested in pursuing this